# TeleBot как узнать айди пользователя в чате по команде /id {username} либо реплай на сообщение

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

TeleBot(PyTelegramBotApi) как узнать айди пользователя в чате по команде /id {username} либо реплай на сообщение

Здравствуйте, хочу чтоб по команде /id {username} я в чате с помощью бота мог узнать айди любого пользователя
**помогите пожалуйста**
пока я нашел только как получить свой id

````
def handler_new_member(message):
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        user_name = message.from_user.first_name
        botik.send_message(message.chat.id, f'User: {user_name}\nID: {user_id}') ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Используй вот этот метод и будет тебе счастье :)

```
def handler_new_member(message):
    get_user = message.reply_to_message.from_user
    botik.send_message(message.chat.id, f'User: {get_user.first_name}\nID{get_user.id}')
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Единственный доступный метод для подобных взаимодействий `getChat` и он уже требует `chat_id` для получения чата

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchat

Чтобы узнать `chat_id` человека по `username` можно использовать базу данных, запоминая его `id` и `username` по сообщению или пересланному сообщению

"Вынуть" данную информацию можно из типа `Message`

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message